# finding flaw in the bogus inductive proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have been looking at this problem for a while, but I cannot find an exact solution to it, although the statement and the conclusion are obviously wrong. Here is the proof:

> Claim: *All tables are the same height*
>
> To prove this by induction, we let P(n) be the statement "For any set
>   of *n* tables, all *n* tables are the same height." If we prove this
>   true for all *n*, it will certainly be true for *n = the number of
>   tables that exist*
>
> Now we proceed by induction on the number of tables. The base case is
>   the case in which there is one table. Since this table is the same
>   height as itself, the base case is true. Now assume that the statement
>   holds for any set of *n* tables, and consider a set of *n + 1* tables.
>
> Put the tables in a line. If we remove the first table, we are left
>   with a set of *n* tables. Then by the inductive hypothesis, these *n*
>   tables must be all be the same height. If, instead, we had removed the
>   last table, we would again have *n* tables, which would now include
>   the first one, and again by inductive hypothesis all *n* tables would
>   be the same height. Therefore, all of the tables must be the same
>   height as, for instance, the second table from the front, and
>   consequently must be the same height as one another. The result then
>   follows from induction.

I do think the base case is true. Although I hate to say that I am getting convinced by this proof, I do have a strong feeling that the flaw is in the inductive step. It's so obvious that I'm confusing myself, but what would be wrong with this proof??

Comment: Does the inductive step reasoning hold going from $n=1$ to $n=2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument fails for $ n=2$

When you set one table aside there is no middle table to make the comparison.

It works for $n\ge 3$ but not for $n=2$

You can not start with $n=2$ either because not every two tables have the same height.